Is it possible to implement org.springframework.http.HttpEntity backed by Consumer<OutputStream>?
My goal is to transfer sufficiently large (>2Gb) blobs via Spring WebClient, the problem is those blobs in general are not stored on the filesystem, but somewhere on the network resource (DB for example), due to that in the most cases I need to open session to the network resource and then release that session upon completion of data transfer. Basically the corresponding code which acquires InputStream and performs housekeeping looks like the following:
@Override
protected InputStream doCreateInputStream(S store, DataTicket dataTicket, Map<String, ContentAttr<?>> contentAttrs) {
    String storeName = store.getName();
    IDfId storeId = store.getObjectId();
    String query = "select content from " + requireValidStoreName(storeName) + " where ticket=:ticket";

    DisposeChain disposeChain = new DisposeChain(null);
    SystemEventLogger systemEventLogger = getSystemEventLogger();

    Supplier<InputStream> supplier = () -> {
        Connection con = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
        disposeChain.prepend(() -> DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, dataSource));
        PreparedStatement stmt;
        boolean success = false;
        try {
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            disposeChain.prepend(() -> closeSilently(stmt, systemEventLogger));
            stmt.setLong(1, dataTicket.getValue());
            ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
            disposeChain.prepend(() -> closeSilently(resultSet, systemEventLogger));

            if (!resultSet.next()) {
                throw ticketNotFound(storeId, dataTicket);
            }

            LobHandler lobHandler = new DefaultLobHandler();
            InputStream is = lobHandler.getBlobAsBinaryStream(resultSet, "content");
            disposeChain.prepend(() -> closeSilently(is, systemEventLogger));
            success = true;
            return is;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw unknownStoreError(storeId, ex);
        } finally {
            if (!success) {
                disposeChain.run();
            }
        }
    };

    InputStream result = new LazyInputStream(supplier, disposeChain);
    resourceHousekeeper.register(result, disposeChain);
    return result;
}

However, the same for Consumer<OutputStream> would look much more straightforward (another possible option is to take advantage of PipedInputStream, which I don't like as well.):
@Override
protected Consumer<OutputStream> doCreatePuller(S store, DataTicket dataTicket, Map<String, ContentAttr<?>> contentAttrs) {
    String storeName = store.getName();
    IDfId storeId = store.getObjectId();
    return os -> {
        RowMapper<Void> rowMapper = (rs, rowNum) -> {
            LobHandler lobHandler = new DefaultLobHandler();
            InputStream is = lobHandler.getBlobAsBinaryStream(rs, "content");
            IOUtils.copy(is, os);
            return null;
        };
        try {
            String statement = "select content from " + requireValidStoreName(storeName) + " where ticket=:ticket";
            MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
            parameters.addValue("ticket", dataTicket.getValue());
            return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(statement, parameters, rowMapper);
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException ex) {
            throw ticketNotFound(storeId, dataTicket);
        }
    };
}

The Q is: is it possible to implement org.springframework.http.HttpEntity which may work like apache's org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity, something like:
public class OutputStreamConsumingEntity extends AbstractHttpEntity implements HttpAsyncContentProducer {

    private final Consumer<OutputStream> outputStreamConsumer;

    public OutputStreamConsumingEntity(@NonNull Consumer<OutputStream> outputStreamConsumer) {
        this.outputStreamConsumer = outputStreamConsumer;
    }

...

    @Override
    public void writeTo(OutputStream outStream) throws IOException {
        outputStreamConsumer.accept(outStream);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStreaming() {
        return true;
    }
}


You may be interested in ServletResponse. Specifically getOutputStream() method.

that is client-side code

it looks like registering your custom org.springframework.http.converter.GenericHttpMessageConverter with special access to resource does suites your needs...

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
